# Ace Editor selected text not highlighting properly

Tags: ace-editor

I am testing the Ace Editor in their [Kitchen Sink demo](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) using the Mono Industrial theme and when I select text, it only highlights part of the line I selected. Here is a screenshot showing what I mean:

https://www.screencast.com/t/SnkUrwMql3J

Is there a setting or CSS hack that might fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with this bit of css:

```
.ace-mono-industrial .ace_string {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in mono industrial theme of ace. It sets background to the text which covers the selection.

You may be able to use a css hack like

```
.ace_line>span {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

or make a more specific selector to match only classes that actually define a background-color

Comment: Is there a setting or CSS hack that might fix it?